# Crash log becomes unknown

Tags: ios, logging, crash

My app crashes and I am finding where the problem is however I am suspecting an abandoned memory.  To find where I went wrong I looked at my crash logs.  However it just displays unknown and the log is this.

```
Incident Identifier: 1EE91CB2-E67A-4D8B-84BF-19E4B3B98747
CrashReporter Key:   b836d79e5ce230ad9b3663fe72a73cbf9aa7bd51
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 27 23:08:32 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2423.3.12~1/RELEASE_ARM64_S5L8960X
Date:                2013-11-17 20:37:45 +0900
Time since snapshot: 105 ms

Free pages:                              6464
Active pages:                            67311
Inactive pages:                          29500
Speculative pages:                       4757
Throttled pages:                         0
Purgeable pages:                         0
Wired pages:                             92047
File-backed pages:                       11060
Anonymous pages:                         90508
Compressions:                            578224
Decompressions:                          122821
Compressor Size:                         60458
Uncompressed Pages in Compressor:        182193
Largest process:   backboardd

Processes
     Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max   fds      [reason]          (state)

      MobileMail <387c38c23acc32dc912a5088ef6b2b66>        14173            14173  200   [vm-pageshortage]  (continuous)
       MobileSMS <fd98ac3fad52357e879f7fbd74f64bd1>         3095             3095  200   [vm-pageshortage]  (background)
            tccd <a4190e0e6f6b3d23b06326c8935a5bb4>          238              238  200   [vm-pageshortage]  (daemon)
             kbd <4350c1efc23b3182809fcb6d8a7885fd>         3645             3645  200   [vm-pageshortage]  (daemon)
      librariand <f9e63967978833b585958d2d38f51e16>         1334             1334  200   [vm-pageshortage]  (daemon)
       MyAPP <7049d9f9e2d932a5a72e8046800f8562>       117514           117514  200   [vm-pageshortage]  (frontmost) (resume)
            ptpd <872030b325d9383b95a5434d41f77b25>         1277             1277  200                      (daemon)
identityservices <cd1fff47d6ad3b0f85cdc5fb39d8b53e>          658              658  100                      (daemon)
             vmd <19de7c691b3137fea83e23261df6802a>          220              220   50                      (daemon)
         imagent <5080234127f5363fb539ffc3965af6e2>          596              596   50                      (daemon)
         syslogd <5c3a246617d3399e977efc84c2e29df2>          709              709   50                      (daemon)
           wifid <ca4f06468bf03d0f8847089e8cd320f1>          614              614   50                      (daemon)
       locationd <10f268a18d5d3343ab21be48bb005ecf>         1502             1502  100                      (daemon)
          powerd <a1fc82c399dc36e2b18a6fbb3d936a88>          164              164  100                      (daemon)
   iaptransportd <4c622f6c4295395997e7a6ec783b4623>          267              267  100                      (daemon)
    mediaserverd <f067d4c2a21a30fbabab30d9c94ccbd3>        95553            95667   50                      (daemon)
   mDNSResponder <2b8ad561938f3fc0a6255b607f503040>          391              391  100                      (daemon)
            apsd <ceb7855af3a63c2682fab13d5e0aeb82>          731              731  100                      (daemon)
     dataaccessd <b155854105f531248c2a44fd3733d59e>         1491             1491  200                      (daemon)
        sharingd <550630f3f5dc3f0aa08ba04876d82e6d>          594              594   50                      (daemon)
    itunesstored <0d023473a4a93c93a531210de784b155>         2020             2020  200                      (daemon)
      calaccessd <d6960604dc2c37499cd597b510055d7e>          667              667  200                      (daemon)
     SpringBoard <fe632b47e4ee342baf4b3701cd11b242>        18539            18539  100                     
      backboardd <2f84882cf3693dfb921f4e0d38966f50>       138729           138729   50                      (daemon)
       fseventsd <a0223d346d4431a5ba1caabf8505b40e>          713              713   50                      (daemon)
       lockdownd <e280cf66209e3be980809a7d93eea76e>          382              382   50                      (daemon)
         configd <bb6e02e801a93ef896f2f3cf5cbb00fe>          710              710   50                      (daemon)
    fairplayd.H2 <da123871e48a3b6a9a2998f428e5c05a>          151              151  100                      (daemon)
      aggregated <6189b3e3d0c83a879b99cf7cd566dffb>         1090             1090  100                      (daemon)
        BTServer <3669aefbfb2e3577b17bde9598feda76>          511              511  100                      (daemon)
       distnoted <c40569cbea09312b9310bc74cbc88e29>          177              177  100                      (daemon)
  UserEventAgent <0d33b64c0c003a65b9a87c6622921781>          796              796  100                      (daemon)
        networkd <c7aa87e0c2d33d379a09598281a5e3ee>          873              873  100                      (daemon)
   biometrickitd <96a562b32d2f3ae0b3d23706c2f5d5ac>          296              296  100                      (daemon)
filecoordination <72a4cec360d435c09cb83d2316317288>          324              324  200                      (daemon)
             ubd <231dc91e9b11307eb98874f9bbfaa86c>         1256             1256  100                      (daemon)
EscrowSecurityAl <e14ee8c5bc0f3447b6cdaad44ab402da>          236              236  200                      (daemon)
     touchsetupd <0c315f01ae8d3675ad1a4eda4c9b18bb>          211              211  200                      (daemon)
notification_pro <72244e97bc7d33408cd01f8c7fb7d2eb>          127              127  200                      (daemon)
      DTMobileIS <5fec282802c03cb49ee4a1cff408ac58>        17147            17147  200                      (daemon)
          cplogd <96828e7047bf36e2a1cdffcc1be700f8>          149              149  200                      (daemon)
     pasteboardd <6a060fcef15735f6884cc7e7f388d7bb>          139              139  200                      (daemon)
   wirelessproxd <9f112d11a5f734019013a43e9fc677a9>           93               93  200                      (daemon)
      CommCenter <ba4a2aecbe913f0ca31c8902e444db0d>         1867             1867  100                      (daemon)
         notifyd <bd919e93d6293562af0b7ec0e21247a0>          300              300  100                      (daemon)

**End**
```

How can I find which line was wrong?

Comment: It seems the phone is running out of memory. Are you trying to allocate huge blocks of memory?

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. I have used the instruments app and saw that I am using so many memory. Yes it is a photo app and I am getting an headache for this problem for about 3 month and just can do it.  my app source code is https://github.com/laryufk/Helper/tree/master so it would be helpful if you would look at it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you on this one. I've never coded for ios before.

Comment: After a quick look at the referenced source code, the `OthersViewController` `viewDidLoad` method loads all the images in the Others directory into `allImagesArray`. Depending on the number and size of the images, this could be the source of the issue. Images can take quite of bit of memory, typically more memory than their size on disk. A more memory efficient approach is to only load images when they are needed, and discard them when they are no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you what code should I do for that. I just want a starting point to work on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your running out of memory... I recommend adding some more code in `didReciveMemoryWarning` getting rid of things that you don't need... If this is only from one person, though, that may not be your app, it may just be that they have an old phone, or they are doing way to many things in the background.

Comment: Apps running in the background would be suspended if they use memory the current app needs. If the app gets killed because of memory usage, it is always the problem of the app using too much memory in the first place. On any device.